# MySQL: how to query to show answers of two users side by side

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some rows

```
questionId userId answers
1          1      1
2          1      0
3          1      1
4          1      1
1          2      1
2          2      1
3          2      0
4          2      0
```

I want this result.

```
questionId user1 user2
1          1     1
2          0     1
3          1     0
4          1     0
```

I don't know how I can get this. Of course I can query each user's answers and merge it with javascript, but I'm curious whether I can get that result with one query. Do I have to use group by or subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by aggregating your table by question and pivoting on the user:

```
SELECT
    questionId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userId = 1 THEN answers END) AS user1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN userId = 2 THEN answers END) AS user2
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    questionId
```

Concepually the way the query works is to take groups of question records, and for each group extract out the answers for each user.  For example, for the first user we take the max of either the answer for user one, or `NULL` if *not* user one.  Since `NULL` values are ignored by max, this just yields the answer we want.  The longer form of the `CASE` expression I wrote is this:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN userId = 1 THEN answers ELSE NULL END)
```

So while aggregating a given question we would conceptually have `MAX` of the user one answer and a bunch of null values, the latter which would be ignored.

## Demo